# Kind of generalization of 'there are at most $n$ linearly independent vectors of length $n$'

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, reference-request

Let $f(n,k)$ be the maximal $m$ for which vectors $\{x_0,\dots,x_{m-1}\}$ of length $n$ with entries in $\{-1,1\}$ exist such that $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle=k$ if $i\neq j$.

In discrete terms, this would mean to ask how many $a$-$b$-sequences of length $n$ you can find such that each two of them differ in exactly $(n-m)/2$ positions.

Calculating $f$ will not be possible, in general, since e.g. $f(4n,0)=4n$ for $n>0$ would correspond with the Hadamard conjecture, but is it possible to give some meaningful upper limits?  For example, Linear algebra tells us that $f(n,0)\le n$, also one can see for example $f(n,-n)=f(n,n-2)=2$ for $n\ge 2$.  Is there anything known along these lines?

Comment: You're asking how big a code can be of a given length and a given minimal distance. Plenty is known, and plenty is unknown.